# How to display sample size in PROC REG output in SAS?

Tags: sas

My question is very simple, is there a way to display sample size in PROC REG output in SAS? I've been googling to no avail.

Comment: Not an expert in this part of SAS, but I think you need PROC POWER (which is licensed for SAS/STAT but may be a separate installation node) to analyze sample size for regressions.  See http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2008/368-2008.pdf for example.

Comment: I don't want to analyze sample size, I just want the PROC REG output to have the sample size displayed somewhere.

Comment: The NOBS table is one of the default outputs with PROC REG.  You should also be able to see the sample size and degrees of freedom in the ANOVA table.

Answer (score 1):

```
ods output nobs=numobs;
      proc reg;
         model y=x;
         run;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
proc reg data=data;
model y=x;
ods select parameterestimates nobs; *can add whatever other tables you are interested in;
run;
```

Here is a list of tables for PROC REG: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_reg_sect051.htm